# Upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10 on netbook: now or later?

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, ubuntu-netbook

I began with installing 9.04 in a netbook (Asus EeePC 1000H), upgraded to 9.10 and have now Lucid Lynx 10.04 (LTS).

Most things tested run pretty good, with the most notable exception being wireless network due to the hardware (Ralink RT2860) which I first tested after the last major upgrade and a few times before giving up (failed to maintain connection to WPA2 networks). Other nuisances are not as important (e.g. some hotkeys work, a couple of them don't), but given that most everything works I'm concerned with doing an upgrade to find most things have been broken and I have to go back and dig up on how to get it to work...

Once in a while, I look up for some posts elsewhere to read up on problems and to find out if they're tame enough to justify an upgrade to 10.10. I'm not in a rush, but I'm not interested in being too left behind some time from now that an upgrade becomes too costly or downright impossible (many things formatted too differently). I'm not even sure if it's possible to "easily" upgrade from LTS to LTS release...

Therefore I ask if it's (in principle) possible to skip releases and only do a major upgrade much later on. For example, is it possible (or advisable) to do an upgrade only when the next LTS comes out (a couple of years from now)? Or is it preferable not to skip releases at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, it's not recommended to skip a release. However, with LTS releases, you have the option of upgrading when the next LTS comes along, skipping the versions in between.

So your options are:

- Upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 (in April 2012)

  or
- Upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10, then Upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 in April 2011

I don't see any problem for you upgrading to 10.10, if anything goes wrong, you know where to come for help. :-)

- Generally speaking, things that break between versions (so called Regressions, things that used to work but don't anymore) are treated very seriously in Ubuntu. They are therefore relatively rare.

  If you do stumple upon one, you also have a good chance of it being fixed in the current release. So long as you file a bug.

Comment: personally I doubt that jbastista will be happy with Unity on an Eee 1000 ;)

Comment: All good answers, but unfortunately "There can be only one" accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to point out.  In 10.10 they changed the user interface drastically for the netbook edition - it's called the Unity desktop.

Also, in the 11.04 alpha (which you can install now), the ubuntu netbook edition merged with the desktop edition, see:
http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/natty/alpha1

Some folks have already tried it out on their netbooks, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVBjv.jpg

I'm about to try it on my eee pc's, as well.

Answer (score 0):

My personal answer would be to install 10.10 desktop edition, and wait for 11.04 so you can have its Unity interface. The Netbook Edition in 10.10 is slower and have some limitations because unity graphics are powered by Mutter instead of Compiz. It didn't work as expected, so they will change it for 11.04.

Unity does look great and helps you with screen space, but you will feel it almost "hangs" on specific situations. After testing netbook edition, I'm using desktop edition again, but using Docky and tweaking the panels so it looks a little close to Unity.

In 11.04, Unity is based on Docky (Canonical hired its developer) and uses Compiz for graphics. I'm sure it will work flawlessly by its release time.